# Using both AWS and GCP at the same time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have a social network website and I stored all the media in S3. I'm planning to use AWS for S3+Lambda and GCP for GCE, Cloudsql. What are the cons of using it this way? Bandwidth between GCP and S3 (since it's not in the same network)?

Thanks.

Comment: Transfer pricing from S3 ($0.09 per GB for first 10TB/month), increased latency, added complexity of managing two clouds, but also if *either* Google Cloud or AWS has a significant service disruption then your service could be down. Why do you want to split things?

Answer (score 1):

Using both services together can make sense when you're leveraging one provider's strengths, or for redundancy / disaster recovery. You might also find the pricing model of one provider suits your use-case better. The tradeoff is inconvenience, extra code to manage interoperability, learning two sets of APIs and libraries, and possibly latency.

A few use-cases I've seen personally:

- Backing up S3 buckets to Cloud Storage in COLDLINE via the Transfer Job system; goal is to protect code and data backups against worst-case S3 data loss or account hacking in AWS
- Using BigQuery to analyze logs pre-processed in AWS EMR and synced into Cloud Storage; depending on your workload BigQuery might cost a lot less than running a Redshift cluster

I've also heard arguments that Google's ML pipelines are superior in some domains, so this might be a common crossover case.

Given the bulk of your infrastructure is already in Google, have you considered using Cloud Functions and Cloud Storage instead of Lambda and S3?